# Why isn't my chatbot responding to the Else statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, chatbot

I had made a Chatbot. I named it Sophie. It was working perfectly, but i thought that what if I make it reply to the things that are not predefined to her differently each time. So I decided to make a random Number generator and specify that if the number is this, then this will happen. While writing the code, it turned a bit complicated and stopped working.
This is the code which is not working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Your new Buddy </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="messagedisplayarea">

    </div>
    <div class="sendarea"> <input type="text" id="input001" placeholder="Message..." class="textinput"> 
      <button onclick="btn001(); btn002(); btn003;" id="submit" class="send"> Send </button> </div>

    <p id="message002" class="myMessage">Me:<br> 
    <p id="message001" class="text">Sophie: <br>Hi!<br></p>
    <script>
      var value = false;
      }
      function options() {
        document.getElementById("optionMenu").innerHTML = "Talking tips with Sophie";
      }
      function btn002() {
        var my = input001.value;
        document.getElementById("message002").innerHTML = "Me: " + my;
      }
      function btn001() {
        var colors001 = input001.value;
        if (colors001 == "hi") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Hi. How are you?";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Hi") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Hey! How are you?";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Hello") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Hey! How are you?";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Atleast type something xD";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "hello") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Hey! How are you?";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "i am fine") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "That is great!";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "How are you?") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML ="Sophie: " +  "I am fine. I am so excited to know more about you!";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Who made you?") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Soham Grover!!";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "I'm fine") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Nice";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "I'm fine") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Nice";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "who made you?") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "It's Soham.";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "I am fine") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Awesome!";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "What is my name?") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "I forgot. Sorry!
        }
        else if (colors001 == "What is your name?")  {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "My Name is Sophie.";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Ok") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Ok";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "I am fine") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Awesome!";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Cool") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Thanks";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Thank you") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "You are Welcome";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Thanks") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Welcome";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Thnx") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "You are Welcome";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Ty") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sphie: " + "You are Welcome";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Why?") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Just like that.";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "You are dumb") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie " + "I'm Sorry if you feel so.";
        }
        else  {
           document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie " + "Sorry?";
        }
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      .text:hover {
        background: lightyellow;
        font-size: 42px;
        font-family: cursive;
      }
      .messagedisplayarea {
        background: lightyellow;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1000px;
        float: left;
        z-index: -1;
        border: 5px solid black;
      }  
      .textinput {
        font-size: 40px;
        width: 730px;
        height: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20%;
        bottom: 60px;
        z-index: 2;
        display: inline;
        border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
        border: 2px solid white;
      }
      .textinput:hover {
        border: 1px solid black;
        font-size: 50px;
      }
      .options {
        position: absolute;
        color: black;
        right: 100px;
        top: 10px;
        height: 5px;
      }
      .optionMenu {
        z-index: 3;
        background: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        color: black;

      }
      .send {
        font-size: 40px;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        left: 70%;
        bottom: 4%;
        z-index: 2;
        display: inline;
        border-radius: 75px 75px 75px 75px;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border:0.1em solid #FFFFFF;
        background: lightgreen;
        transition-delay:all 0.3s ease-in;
      }
      .send:hover {
        font-size: 50px;
        color: yellow;
        background: yellowgreen;
      }
      .sendarea {
        display: inline;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
      }
      .myMessage {
        color: black;
        font-size: 40px;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        width: 300px;
        left: 55%;
        background: yellow;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        transition: all 1s ease-in;
      }
      .myMessage:hover {
        background: white;
        font-size: 42px;
        font-family:cursive;
      }
      .text {
        font-size: 60px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 10%;
        top: 200px;
        background: white;
        padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        font-family: monospace;
        width: 300px; 
        height: auto;
        transition: all 1s ease-in;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      @media(max-width: 768px) {
        .myMessage {
          font-size: 60px;
          font-family: monospace;
          text-align: center;
          position: absolute;
          top: 2px;
          width: 300px;
          height: 200px;
          left: 60%;
          background: yellow;
          border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        }
        .text {
          font-size: 60px;
          position: absolute;
          left: 10%;
          top: 150px;
          background: white;
          padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
          border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
          font-family: monospace;
          width: 300px; 
          height: auto;
          transition: all 1s ease-in;
          z-index: 1;
        }
      }

    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Your new Buddy </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="messagedisplayarea">

    </div>
    <div class="sendarea"> <input type="text" id="input001" placeholder="Message..." class="textinput"> 
      <button onclick="btn001(); btn002(); btn003;" id="submit" class="send"> Send </button> </div>

    <p id="message002" class="myMessage">Me:<br> 
    <p id="message001" class="text">Sophie: <br>Hi!<br></p>
    <script>
      var value = false;
    function btn003() {  
      var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
      if (value==true && random==1) {
        document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Sorry?";
      }
      else if (value==true && random==2) {
        document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "I didn't get that.";
      }
      else if (value==true && random==3) {
        document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Ughhh! I'm Sorry!";
      }
      else if (value==true && random==4) {
        document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Sorry, but I didn't understand.";
      }
      else if (value==true && random==5) {
        document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "This is difficult for me to understand";
      }
      else if (value==true && random==6) {
        document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Error!";
      }
      else if (value==true && random==7) {
        document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Unknown Spelling Error";
      }
      else if (value==true && random==8) {
        document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "This is hard for me to understand";
      }
      else if (value==true && random==9) {
        document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Can you say that again?";
      }
      else if (value==true && random==10) {
        document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "What?????";
      }
      }
      function options() {
        document.getElementById("optionMenu").innerHTML = "Talking tips with Sophie";
      }
      function btn002() {
        var my = input001.value;
        document.getElementById("message002").innerHTML = "Me: " + my;
      }
      function btn001() {
        var colors001 = input001.value;
        if (colors001 == "hi") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Hi. How are you?";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Hi") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Hey! How are you?";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Hello") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Hey! How are you?";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Atleast type something xD";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "hello") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Hey! How are you?";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "i am fine") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "That is great!";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "How are you?") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML ="Sophie: " +  "I am fine. I am so excited to know more about you!";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Who made you?") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Soham Grover!!";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "I'm fine") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Nice";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "I'm fine") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Nice";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "who made you?") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "It's Soham.";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "I am fine") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Awesome!";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "What is my name?") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "I forgot. Sorry!
        }
        else if (colors001 == "What is your name?")  {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "My Name is Sophie.";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Ok") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Ok";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "I am fine") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Awesome!";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Cool") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Thanks";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Thank you") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "You are Welcome";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Thanks") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Welcome";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Thnx") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "You are Welcome";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Ty") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sphie: " + "You are Welcome";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "Why?") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie: " + "Just like that.";
        }
        else if (colors001 == "You are dumb") {
          document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = "Sophie " + "I'm Sorry if you feel so.";
        }
        else  {
          value = true;
        }
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      .text:hover {
        background: lightyellow;
        font-size: 42px;
        font-family: cursive;
      }
      .messagedisplayarea {
        background: lightyellow;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1000px;
        float: left;
        z-index: -1;
        border: 5px solid black;
      }  
      .textinput {
        font-size: 40px;
        width: 730px;
        height: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20%;
        bottom: 60px;
        z-index: 2;
        display: inline;
        border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
        border: 2px solid white;
      }
      .textinput:hover {
        border: 1px solid black;
        font-size: 50px;
      }
      .options {
        position: absolute;
        color: black;
        right: 100px;
        top: 10px;
        height: 5px;
      }
      .optionMenu {
        z-index: 3;
        background: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        color: black;

      }
      .send {
        font-size: 40px;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        left: 70%;
        bottom: 4%;
        z-index: 2;
        display: inline;
        border-radius: 75px 75px 75px 75px;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border:0.1em solid #FFFFFF;
        background: lightgreen;
        transition-delay:all 0.3s ease-in;
      }
      .send:hover {
        font-size: 50px;
        color: yellow;
        background: yellowgreen;
      }
      .sendarea {
        display: inline;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
      }
      .myMessage {
        color: black;
        font-size: 40px;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        width: 300px;
        left: 55%;
        background: yellow;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        transition: all 1s ease-in;
      }
      .myMessage:hover {
        background: white;
        font-size: 42px;
        font-family:cursive;
      }
      .text {
        font-size: 60px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 10%;
        top: 200px;
        background: white;
        padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        font-family: monospace;
        width: 300px; 
        height: auto;
        transition: all 1s ease-in;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      @media(max-width: 768px) {
        .myMessage {
          font-size: 60px;
          font-family: monospace;
          text-align: center;
          position: absolute;
          top: 2px;
          width: 300px;
          height: 200px;
          left: 60%;
          background: yellow;
          border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        }
        .text {
          font-size: 60px;
          position: absolute;
          left: 10%;
          top: 150px;
          background: white;
          padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
          border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
          font-family: monospace;
          width: 300px; 
          height: auto;
          transition: all 1s ease-in;
          z-index: 1;
        }
      }

    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to end your first `else if` code block with a standalone `else`. Few pointers when comparing a boolean value, if such value is true you can just use the variable name, like so `if (value) { ... }`. You can also make your code more "readable" by using a `switch` statement in favor of your `if else` block when appropriate of course. If the `CSS` is not relevant to you problem leave it out of the post.

Comment: You are missing a closing `</p>` here`<p id="message002" class="myMessage">Me:<br>`

Comment: I can see the 2 blocks of code are different but please tell us what it is, be more specific

Comment: Hi. Can you tell which code blocks are different?

Comment: Yes but it is not clear why you add them, which one is your working code, and which is your failed attempt, the code is just there with no explanation as of what they represent with regards to your problem at hand